# git annex: 'put' functionality as opposed to 'get'

Tags: git, git-annex

The git annex documentation gives an example of using `get`:

```
# git annex sync laptop
# git annex get .
get my_cool_big_file (from laptop...) ok
get iso/debian.iso (from laptop...) ok
```

https://git-annex.branchable.com/walkthrough/#index5h2

Is there a way to do the opposite, i.e. once synchronisied with the remote repo called "laptop", directly put the actual file content directly into the "laptop"'s annex storage? E.g.

```
# git annex sync laptop
# git annex put .
put my_cool_big_file (to laptop...) ok
put iso/debian.iso (to laptop...) ok
```

Answer (score 1):

The subcommands are `copy` or `move`, and you have to specify the remote:

```
git annex copy --to laptop
```

More info from the documentation: [copy](https://git-annex.branchable.com/git-annex-copy/), [move](https://git-annex.branchable.com/git-annex-move/)